# reading formatted data from text file in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, formatted

I have been trying to read some numbers from formatted text file.
I want to keep some number of columns from numerous columns, and I want to repeat it to the end of file (multiple rows or lines).

This is the code that I wrote to do that but it only reads one single line of the data.

```
fid = fopen ('L0512164529','r+');
num_ints = 47;
num_rows = 50;
features = struct;

format =['L%d,',repmat('%f,' , 1 , num_ints-1),'%f'];
[r_dat,l] = textscan(fid, format, num_rows);
features.name=r_dat{1};
features.bodyposfeat=[r_dat{2:end}];

fclose(fid);
```

Every line starts with a number with starting `L`. The first two rows of the file are:

```
L0512164529,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1376599,-0.4387758,0.4723490,0.751‌​9389,0.4742642,-0.8703301
L0512164529,0.0001816,0.0000005,-0.0005697,-1.0843741,0.0001816,0.0000005,-0.000‌​5697,-1.0843741,0.1433973
```

Comment: Give an example of the first couple of lines of your file.

Comment: L0512164529,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.1376599,-0.4387758,0.4723490,0.7519389,0.4742642,-0.8703301.....
L0512164529,0.0001816,0.0000005,-0.0005697,-1.0843741,0.0001816,0.0000005,-0.0005697,-1.0843741,0.1433973.....

These are first two rows of the text. Every line starts with a number with starting L.

Comment: Your lines have variable columns?

Comment: You can also try `fid = fopen(file)`, then use a `while` loop: `while ~feof` `data(k,:) = fread(fid);k=k+1;` `end`

Comment: If the lines have different numbers of columns, then textscan is not the right tool.

Comment: How big is your file? I'm lazy so I just do `t = readtable('somefile.csv');` then grab the columns I want.

Comment: Actually I have many number of rows and columns in my text file I copied only a few examples of these at my comment, Let me clarify the problem,
I have 1385 rows(lines) and 907 columns(without the L-xxx number) I want to read all rows with only 47(or some specified number) columns by using textscan.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the correct number of `%f` format specifiers in your format string.  It looks like you probably need to use the following format statement:

```
format =['L%d,',repmat('%f,' , 1 , num_ints-2),'%f'];  %% changed to ( num_ints - 2)
```

assuming that `num_ints` is the number of columns.  When I tried your code with your sample data, it worked when I change num_ints to 14 since your examples only have 16 columns and the first one is specified separately with `L%d,`.  When I increase num_ints above 14, it only parses 1 line of the file.

So to be clear, if `num_ints` is the number of columns, including the first column that has the L-name, then using `num_ints-2` in the format string creation should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually I have many number of rows and columns in my text file I copied only a few examples of these at my comment, Let me clarify the problem,
I have 1385 rows(lines) and 907 columns(without the L-xxx number) I want to read all rows with only 47(or some specified number) columns by using textscan.

Comment: well, as far as terminology goes, if you have a variable number of columns (which it sounds like you do), then that's important to state in the problem description.  Textscan will not work for you if you want to skip rows that do not have 47 columns.  I'll add another answer with a simple alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it, if you have a variable number of columns in your file.

```
filename = 'temp.txt'
fid = fopen(filename, 'rt');
if fid < 0
    error('Error opening file %s\n', filename); % exit point
end

desired_number_of_columns = 48;  %% 1 for the name, and 47 for the data
number_of_rows = 1385;  %% data structure won''t have this many rows, because some will be skipped

features.name=zeros(number_of_rows,1);
features.bodyposfeat=zeros(number_of_rows, desired_number_of_columns-1);

cntr = 1
while true
    tline = fgetl(fid);  %% read file one line at a time
    if ~ischar(tline), break; end; % break out of loop at end of file

    splitLine = strsplit(tline, ',');  %% separate into columns
    if (length(splitLine) ~= desired_number_of_columns)  %% check for the correct number of columns
        continue;
    end

    features.name(cntr) = str2num(splitLine{1}(2:end)); %% chop off first character and convert to number; does not check for 'L' specifically
    features.bodyposfeat(cntr, 1:desired_number_of_columns-1) = str2double(splitLine(2:end));  %% convert strings to numbers and save the rest of the columns as data
    cntr = cntr + 1;
end

%% optional - delete extra rows in the data structure that were never populated
features.name(cntr:end) = [];
features.bodyposfeat(cntr:end,:) = [];

fclose(fid)
```